# Have set up mongodb, mongoose etc but when I try and add something to the database it doesn't actually add it

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm using localhost and have all the modules set up correctly and I've checked that the database exists.  When I type in localhost:3000/pods/add?firstName='John' it's supposed to add it to the database, but for some reason it isn't working.

```
var express = require('express');
var _ = require('underscore');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var podStore = require('./lib/pod-handler.js');
var podsLibrary = require('./lib/pods-library.js');
var podList = [];

var mongoPort = 27017;
var app = express();
var port = 3000;
var router = express.Router();
var pods = podsLibrary.list();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:'+mongoPort+'/pods');

router.route('/').get(function(request, response) {
  //console.log('You hit an empty URL .. :(');
    response.status(503).send("Service Unavailable");
});

router.route('/lib').get(function(request, response) {
  //console.log('You hit an empty URL .. :(');
    response.status(200).send("Cool beans!");
});

router.route('/pods/list').get(function(request, response){
  if(!pods){
    return response.status(503).send("Service Unavailable");
  }
  return response.status(200).send(makeReadableList(pods));

  function makeReadableList(pods){
    var podsHtml = " ";
    _.each(pods, function(value, key){podsHtml = podsHtml + key});
    return podsHtml;
  }
});

router.route('/pods/add').post(function(request, response){
  if (!request.query){
    return response.status(400).send("Please give first name");
  }
  var payload = request.query;
  if (!payload.firstName){
    return response.status(400).send("give name");
  }
  podStore.save({
    firstName: payload.firstName,
    lastName: payload.lastName

  }, function(){
    return response.status(200).send(payload.firstName + " has been added!");
    var space = " ";
    _.each(pods, function(value, key) {
      key + space;
      return space + payload.firstName + payload.secondName;
    });
  });
});


router.route('/pods').get(function(request, response) {
  //console.log("We reached the POD page -- Yay! :D");
  response.status(200).send("Server unavailable");
});


app.use('/', router);
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('App listening on port %s', port);
});
```

I've checked over my code countless times and I can't seem to find the problem.

Here's the pod-handler file.

```
var PodDoc = require('../models/pods.js');

module.exports = {
  save: save
}

function save(pod, callback){
  var podToSave = new PodDoc();
  podToSave.firstName = pod.firstName;
  podToSave.lastName = pod.lastName;
  /*podToSave.skills = pod.skills;
  podToSave.avatarUrl = pod.avatarUrl;
  podToSave.address = {
    number: pod.address.number,
    lineOne: pod.address.lineOne,
    lineTwo: pod.address.lineTwo,
    postcode: pod.address.postcode
  }
  podToSave.phoneNumbers = {
    mobile: pod.phoneNumbers.mobile,
    landline: pod.phoneNumbers.landline
  }*/
  podToSave.save(function(err){
    if(err){

      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("Working");
      callback();
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: How are you defining your Mongoose models in `lib/pod-handler.js`?

Comment: Just added the code from pod-handler to the question.

Comment: Is there any errors in console?

Comment: _When I type in localhost:3000/pods/add?firstName='John' it's supposed to add it to the database_ you tried this in browser page? You just open that url(just like google.com) and expect to add John to database, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*When I type in localhost:3000/pods/add?firstName='John' it's supposed to add it to the database*
If i understand correctly, you want to open this url in browser, and expect to have a record *John* in database.
Change router request type to GET, this

```
router.route('/pods/add').post(/*omitted*/);
```

to this

```
router.route('/pods/add').get(/*omitted*/);
```

Server is expecting POST request, but browser cannot handle it without FORM element or ajax request, browsers usually uses GET request, i mean when you open your url, it send GET request to server

Comment: It doesn't matter, specially this url `/pods/add` currently is POST which won't work, you have to use GET

Answer (score 0):

There may be a typo error as in the url you are using port 300 where as the port configured for localhost is 3000.
When I type in localhost:300/pods/add?firstName='John'

Comment: Yeah that was a typo when asking the question.  Sorry about that.